# Can we take steps to limit crap questions?

Tags: discussion

I've been seeing a lot of crap these days mostly by less than 50 rep users. The 1 rep policy is not helping this. What I intend to make a change concerns users less than 50 reps (Just my though. Community feedback would be helpful to decide this limit.)

### So here it goes:

On each downvote(only to the question), there should be a separate count, say `net` whose default value is `0` which *can* go negative. So if a user who starts his first question and gets 5 downvotes, the net will become `-5`

And if the `net` goes below `-2` (also need community feedback here) the OP should not be able to ask his next question. For that he needs to improve his `net` score.

For which an upvote on either question or answer should add `+2` to the `net`. (Again that +2 is community decider)(Also what about edits?? Community Feedback on this!!)

### Pros:

- After a crappy question, if a user wants to continue asking questions, he compulsorily needs to *contribute* something good to survive here.
- The Question Ban can be taken off in case this or similar system with minor adjustment, giving the user complete control of his being banned or not. OP decides his fate and it is something like give and take policy.
- We can immediately control craps being posted.

### Cons:

- The critique comments left by future readers of this question, as I honestly cannot not see any cons in this.

So what does the community has to say? Also the `net` score should be showed to the user, so he knows what he has to do.

Comment: Would this be additional to the current question rate limit and the upcoming quality filter combined with the new triage queue?

Comment: Doesn't work, lots of SO users create a new account every time they ask a question.  But yeah, there would be a *lot* less crap if they had to use the same account and using a synonym would be an earned privilege.

Comment: There are quality improvements SE is trying to bring in order to reduce crap. However, your suggestion is too harsh towards new users due to the reasons mentioned by Bart and BoltClock in their comments.

Answer (score 8):

No, this doesn't sound like a good idea.

First, I fail to see what it adds to the [Ongoing Quality Improvement Project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236537/lets-have-an-explicit-triage-system-for-questions-from-new-users) specially the [rate limiter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236568/breaking-down-question-blocks-lets-talk-about-rate-limits) and the [ban warnings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236802/158100)

A lot of measures are in place after the fact. It would be more interesting to have ways to help users *before* they post a low quality question. And that is not done by adding more stuff in the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) or the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq) or have yet another score. I was more thinking of someone tapping on their shoulder, saying: *You better don't post that...*

Comment: How about a unicorn head-stabbing their avatar?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yeah, that sounds more like it...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi could we just get that for all users?

Comment: @Bart, you mean, including the ones who are about to ask great questions? You *may* be able to pull something off the hats routines we're about to dust up, but that would have to be on an opt-in basis ;)